# NPM install doesn't delete /tmp on successful exit when installing packages that have shrinkwrap

Tags: node.js, npm, tmp

I'm using npm to install some internally developed packages on a Ubuntu 14.04 server.  During install, a folder is created under /tmp.  According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html), the temporary folder should be deleted on successful exit, but it isn't happening.  I've checked the exit code, and it's zero as expected, so what else could be causing this?  It's clogging up my build server, which currently has quite limited disk space available - I can work round this by using a cronjob to clean up, or by adding more disk space, but I want to know the cause!

Running npm v 1.4.28.

**Update**: This only happens when the package you are installing has been shrinkwrapped using the `npm shrinkwrap` command.  Confirmed as a problem in npm v 1.4.28 and 2.1.10.  See the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6855#issuecomment-66121083).

Edit: I've also run the install in verbose mode, it ends with

```
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

There's lots of mention of /tmp in the output in terms of writing to it, and untarring things there, but no obvious attempt to clean it up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in npm.  I've raised an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6855).  It only happens when you install a shrinkwrapped package.

As a workaround in the meantime, I ended up just running a cronjob that deletes any of these folders that are more than 10 minutes old, by creating a script in /etc/cron.hourly.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Removes any folder starting with npm- in the /tmp folder.
sudo find /tmp/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'npm-*' -type d -mmin +10 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

**Update**

Although this is confirmed as a bug, it doesn't sound like it will be fixed in npm2, so you're left with a choice between using npm3 or a workaround such as the script above.  If you're on Windows, there's a Powershell version of the script on the [Github page](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6855#issuecomment-192586449).

Comment: on Mac, you will need `find -L` for this to work because `/tmp` is a symlink on Mac.

Comment: You can also just `rm -rf /tmp/npm-*`

Comment: @caarlos0 you can't do that, because some of those files may still be in use by running installs.

Comment: @IBam oh yes, but, assuming there is no `npm` running, thats the easiest way.

Comment: The point is to run it in a cronjob, you can't make that assumption! Well, you can but eventually you'll be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Add a one-liner to postinstall script inside the package.json, which will run at the end of every npm install:

`{
    "scripts": {
      "postinstall": "ppid=$(ps -p ${1:-$$} -o ppid=;); ppid=$(echo ${ppid}|tr -d '[[:space:]]'); if [ -z ${npm_config_tmp} ]; then npm_config_tmp=/tmp; fi; rm -rf \"${npm_config_tmp}\"/npm-${ppid}*"
    }
}`

If you don't like one-liners, there is also a separate script for that available.

https://gist.github.com/nemisj/11f6d01ef9638af283d3

Comment: Interesting workaround, but don't you then need to add that to every package.json you are working on?

Comment: Sure, but how much separate packages are you working on? For me it was a better solution, since I don't have to setup stuff on a machine itself and functionality is embedded into the project.

Comment: I accept that if you're working on very few packages this is fine... as long as you're end-user has bash.  May have problems on Windows? I don't know what the result would be then - would the install fail?